# Property 'captureStream' does not exist on type 'HTMLVideoElement'

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, webrtc, capturestream

I'm making a simple project that uses WebRTC in React with typescript.

I was following [MDN HTMLMediaElement.captureStream()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/captureStream).

```js
const vid: HTMLVideoElement | null = document.querySelector("video");
if (vid) {
   vid.captureStream();
}

.
.
.

<video id="myVid"></video>
```

But I'm getting this error,

```
Property 'captureStream' does not exist on type 'HTMLVideoElement'.ts(2339)
```

I've even tried,

```
const vid: HTMLMediaElement | null = document.querySelector("video");
```

What am I doing wrong??

### Edit

I tried

```
const videoCont = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);

var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL
const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(e)
if (videoCont.current) {
         videoCont.current.src = fileURL;
         videoCont.current.play = async () => {
              const mediaStream = videoCont.current?.captureStream();
       }
   }
```

Still the same error,

```
Property 'captureStream' does not exist on type 'HTMLVideoElement'.
```

### Edit 2

I looked into [unresolved method captureStream on HTMLCanvasElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50651091/unresolved-method-capturestream-on-htmlcanvaselement).

Apparently this is still an experimental feature not supported on all browsers. Will have to wait.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [unresolved method captureStream on HTMLCanvasElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50651091/unresolved-method-capturestream-on-htmlcanvaselement)

Comment: I guess, it just says that this is an experimental feature yet.

Comment: `(videoCont.current? as any).captureStream();` this would silence the error, `captureStream` on mediaelement is experimental and not available in TS yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The property looks [experimental](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement) and might not be added in [TS](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.htmlmediaelement.html) yet. You can use `any` or event make your own type:

```
interface HTMLMediaElementWithCaptureStream extends HTMLMediaElement{
  captureStream(): MediaStream;
}
```

Comment: I tried to create my own type, but the ```captureStream()``` just returned ```undefined```. Guess I will have to wait till TS supports this

Comment: The code above will only mitigate the checking TS does. If your browser is returning undefined, then it might not have support for this.

Comment: but from [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/captureStream#browser_compatibility) link we can see that most modern browsers do support ```captureStream()``` and I'm testing on latest version of FF

Comment: Hm. Check if it should be play or onplay.

Comment: HTMLCanvasElement already has captureStream type

Answer (score 1):

`captureStream()` method exists in HTMLCanvasElements so change your type to `HTMLCanvasElement` or `any`.

Comment: Then how would I use ```videoCont.current.play();``` or similar functions

Comment: using ```any```, I can't seem to update seek bar. using ```HTMLCanvasElement```, I can't use ANY video player functions